# Ubuntu 14.04 terminal corrupt

Tags: linux, terminal, ubuntu-14.04

In my Ubuntu terminal, somehow my terminal system name has been mounted to the root directory. Anyway, my terminal is displaying this:

```
admin.Ubuntu:/$
```

Instead of

```
admin.Ubuntu:~$
```

Now i cannot even see my home files and directories. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can verify what is defined setting for your shell prompt. What is the output of following command?

- `pwd`
- `echo $PS1`
- `echo $PS2`
- `echo $PS3`

Then cross check that the path between current path and your shell prompt.

**EDIT**

Based on the updated question, it seems `pwd` is at root folder `/`, and `$PS1` is set to `${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$`

- So the value of `pwd`, explains why your prompt is different.
- Also read what that definition of `PS1` do? https://askubuntu.com/questions/372849/what-does-debian-chrootdebian-chroot-do-in-my-terminal-prompt/372862#372862

You may also want to check if your `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.profile`, `~/.bashrc` are correct. To do so read for the order in which these files are read by `bash` ( see `man bash` for `FILES` section ).

Comment: The first command just displays a forward slash /. The second command displays "${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$", then the third command just displays >

Comment: I am new to linux and now confused with all this. I dot have the file /etc/debian_chroot.

Comment: I don't have a Ubuntu machine handy right now. Can you try to create a new user, and then compare your `~/.bashrc`  and `~/.bash_profile` files ?

Comment: Neither files exists on my Ubuntu

Comment: Alright, then once you create a new account, what files are present in the home folder? ( along with dot files )

Comment: I just see folders of my root directory. About the bashrc file, i have {{/etc/bash.bashrc}}, {{/etc/profile.d}}, and the {{/etc/profile}} files. Ot one point i added some code to the /etc/profile file and thats when i experienced this issue following a reboot. But i have the added extra lines of code, but still get this chroot issue.